# trouble with autentication on a realm server - Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file

Tags: android, authentication, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I’m new to Realm. I’m having trouble with the autentication of different users on a realm server.
I wrote a few lines of code to test subsequent logins to the server and domain separation.

- I  log in with a first user pluto@qui.li
- I populate a RealmObject (UserApp) and I save it to the server
- I log out with pluto@qui.li
- I  log in with a second user paperino@qui.li
- I check that UserApp is not populated for this user (domain separation)
- I log out with paperino@qui.li
- Then I try again to log in with the first user pluto@qui.li but I get the following error message:

.

```
*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file.
Cached configuration:
realmDirectory: /data/user/0/com.my.assistant/files/realm-object-server/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc
realmFileName : default
canonicalPath: /data/data/com.my.assistant/files/realm-object-server/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/default
key: [length: 0]
schemaVersion: 0
migration: null
deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
durability: FULL
schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@5208266
readOnly: false
compactOnLaunch: null
serverUrl: realm://localhost:9080/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/default
user: {UserId: 621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc, AuthUrl: http://localhost:9080/auth, IsValid: false, Sessions: 0}
errorHandler: com.my.assistant.LoginInstrTest2$1@397b523
deleteRealmOnLogout: false
waitForInitialRemoteData: false
New configuration:
realmDirectory: /data/user/0/com.my.assistant/files/realm-object-server/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc
realmFileName : default
canonicalPath: /data/data/com.my.assistant/files/realm-object-server/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/default
key: [length: 0]
schemaVersion: 0
migration: null
deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
durability: FULL
schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@5208266
readOnly: false
compactOnLaunch: null
serverUrl: realm://localhost:9080/621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc/default
user: {UserId: 621c2e6db5e0cf421741f6e9a428c3dc, AuthUrl: http://localhost:9080/auth, IsValid: true, Sessions: 0}
errorHandler: com.my.assistant.LoginInstrTest2$1@cdafa20
deleteRealmOnLogout: false
waitForInitialRemoteData: false
at io.realm.RealmCache.validateConfiguration(RealmCache.java:461)
at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:337)
at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:284)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:301)
at com.my.assistant.LoginInstrTest2.setConfigurationSyncUser(LoginInstrTest2.java:149)
at com.my.assistant.LoginInstrTest2.loginUser(LoginInstrTest2.java:129)
at com.my.assistant.LoginInstrTest2.veryfyRealmUserInstance(LoginInstrTest2.java:98)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2074)*
```

Can anybody tell me why? My intent with this code is to test an embryonic login/logout for an android application using realm. The user should log in and out of the application using different credentials. It sound to me like there should be a way to get the previously created  SyncConfiguration for that user instead of creating a new one… but, if this is the case, I don’t know how to do that….

This is my code:

//-----------main code:

```
  SyncUser userLogged;

    //Login with first user. This time the login completes successfully
    userLogged = loginUser("pluto@qui.li", "pluto");

    insertUserAppSyncRealm();

    RealmResults<UserApp> res = realm.where(UserApp.class)
            .beginsWith("username", "situs")
            .findAll();
    System.out.println(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Size table pippo " + res.size());
    UserApp resUser = res.last();
    System.out.println(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ID " + resUser.getId());

    userLogged.logout();

    //Login with second user OK
    userLogged = loginUser("paperino@qui.li", "paperino");

    RealmResults<UserApp> res2 = realm.where(UserApp.class)
            .beginsWith("username", "situs")
            .findAll();  //arrivato qui da "Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file"
    System.out.println(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Size table usertest " + res2.size());

    userLogged.logout();

    //Login again with first user. This time the login fails ("Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file")
    userLogged = loginUser("pluto@qui.li", "pluto");

    RealmResults<UserApp> res3 = realm.where(UserApp.class)
            .beginsWith("username", "situs")
            .findAll();
    System.out.println(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Size table pippo " + res3.size());

    userLogged.logout();
```

//-----------used functions:

```
public SyncUser loginUser(String username, String password) {
    SyncUser userLogged;
    SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username, password, false);
    userLogged = SyncUser.login(myCredentials, authURL);
    setConfigurationSyncUser(userLogged);
    return userLogged;
}

public void setConfigurationSyncUser(SyncUser user) {
    String user1RealmUrl = "realm://localhost:9080/~/default";
    SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, user1RealmUrl).
            errorHandler(new SyncSession.ErrorHandler() {
                public void onError(SyncSession session, ObjectServerError error) {
                    fail("Realm unexpected error: " + error);
                }
            })
            .build();

        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);  //fails ("Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file")
}

public void insertUserAppSyncRealm() {
    UserApp user = new UserApp();
    populateUser(user);
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.insert(user);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

private void populateUser(UserApp user) {
    user.setUsername("situs@qui.it");
    user.setPassword("12345678");
    user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
```

Thanks in advance for your kind advice...

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
public void setConfigurationSyncUser(SyncUser user) {
    String user1RealmUrl = "realm://localhost:9080/~/default";
    class SyncErrorHandler implements SyncSession.ErrorHandler {
        @Override
        public void onError(SyncSession session, ObjectServerError error) {
            fail("Realm unexpected error: " + error);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return SyncErrorHandler.class.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
            return obj != null && obj instanceof SyncErrorHandler;
        }
    };
    SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, user1RealmUrl).
            errorHandler(new SyncErrorHandler())
            .build();

        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
}
```

Comment: This should work. The problem is that your error handler is different between the two configurations: `com.my.assistant.LoginInstrTest2$1@397b523` vs `com.my.assistant.LoginInstrTest2$1@cdafa20`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... I also try to completely remove the error handler but I get the same error... any other idea?

Comment: Nothing special, the error seams to be the same: "Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file."

Comment: Okay, but there are **details** underneath that shows what was different!

Comment: I don't know how to show you... this comment field is too short to cut&paste the output :(

Comment: Edit the question :D